# PHP get CGI Page Contents

Tags: php, cgi

I am familar with PHP but not so much with CGI. There is a page that I would like to get the contents from (specifically one that has just a jpg image) that has the extension .cgi

My question: is there a way to get the contents(or image) from a CGI page using PHP? Using file_get_contents($url) and imagecreatefromjpeg($url) gives me an error that says it failed to open the stream however I am able to right click on the image and save it as a jpg. I assume that is because the browser can recognize it as an image.

EDIT: My problem might be that the connection is just timing out.

Comment: file_get_contents not working for you..?

Comment: no it says it failed to open the stream and the connection timed out.

Comment: it probably says more than failed to open stream...

Comment: The error it gives is: Warning: file_get_contents(http://website.com/image.cgi) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/test.php on line 6

Comment: I think that it is timing out because the image.cgi might be outputing a stream instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other cgi pages that I have tried getting using file_get_contents and curl have worked for me. It seems that just this particular page doesn't work for some reason. I assume that it is just a connection issue that prevents me from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with the binary mode flag and then fwrite() it elsewhere with a .jpg filename.

Comment: fopen($url, 'b') and fopen($url, 't') still says it failed to open stream.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using cURL for that, which is somewat faster then file_get_contents:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$yourUrlHere);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: no luck, thanks for the answer though. Is there any way to use curl to capture from a stream?